# Configurating SQL Server 2008 Management Studio each time I build setup Project

Tags: deployment, windows-installer, setup-project, setup-deployment

I've Created Setup Project that only contains files to be Copied to specified folder, Each time I build the setup Project a new popup window appear saying "Please wait while windows configure Sql server 2008 SP1 Management Studio" and this take about 5 minute until it finish then to start the building process.

This happens only on my machine, even when trying to build new empty setup project!!

Why this happens, and how can I get rid of this..

Thanks in advance..
Regards

[image: SQLServerConfigure]

Comment: I just reproduced the issue by installing then uninstalling VS2013 Beside VS2010